# Django: Is there a way to get django to handle 502 errors simiilar to how it handlese 404 and 500 errors?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I've created some custom error pages for errors 404 and 500 using

- handler404
- handler500

that were added to my urls.py and they are working fine. But what I was also wondering if there was a solution out there that would allow me to redirect to a custom error page for 502 Bad Gateway errors.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/shanx/django-maintenancemode this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Nginx it will always serve it's own 502 page. That's from my experience. Here's a useful link - http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189334. I know it's on Ruby forum but it applies to any Nginx conf.